# Conversion of large number to Julian format in a regexp_replace

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I need to replace only the number and keep the remaining portion.
Example:

34HUNTAVE ==> 34THHUNTAVE

1232432GRACE ST ==> 1232432NDGRACE ST

1232433GRACE ST ==> 1232433RDGRACE ST

The problem is Julian format is giving error on large number.How can I make it work.

```
   Does Not Work
    ------------
        SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('10425222GRACEST','[[:digit:]]+', 
         TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (REGEXP_REPLACE ('10425222GRACEST','[^[:digit:]]'),'J'),'fmJTH')) FROM dual;

     Works Fine
    ----------
         SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('10425BCST','[[:digit:]]+', 
         TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (REGEXP_REPLACE ('10425BCST','[^[:digit:]]'),'J'),'fmJTH')) FROM dual;
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting with large numbers?

Comment: @RajA - are you getting an `ORA-01854`? The logic you're using is relies on a Julian conversion to a date, and the Julian range for Oracle dates (minimum 1/1/4712 BC and maximum 12/31/9999 AD) is 1 to 5,373,484. Once you exceed that you run into the ORA-01854 error. BTW, what do you intend to do with addresses such as "123 E 22nd St" or "10844 RD1" or "1773 US 23"?

Comment: hmm I am basically appending TH , ND , RD , ST to the number portion of the street address.Is there a way that I look at the last digit of the number and replace with the Julian format and then append that to the original number.But how do I achieve that.Eg: 10425222GRACEST, take the last digit (2) which is 2ND in J then remove 2 and append ND to 10425222ND

Comment: BTW, what do you intend to do with addresses such as "123 E 22nd St" or "10844 RD1" or "1773 US 23"? I have two columns house number and street address so 123 E will fall in house number col,if the data is clean.I know not all cases will cover up,but I am trying to reduce max permutations.But if anyone can help me on this,it will be great

Comment: @Raj - How do you know that 1232433GRACE ST converts to 1232433RDGRACE? Why RD and not ST or AVE? I think you need to fix your data as your requirement is not realistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
  string,
  regexp_substr(string, '^\D*\d+') ||
  regexp_substr(to_char(to_date(
    regexp_replace(string, '^\D*\d*?(\d{1,3})(\D|$).*$', '100\1'), 
    'J'), 'fmjth'), '\D*$') ||
  regexp_replace(string, '^\D*\d+(.*)$', '\1') as new_string
FROM your_table
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6870b/2)

Comment: Awesome!Fantastic! How does even one interpret this.Is there a tool to get expertise in it?Thanks a lot Egor! you solved my other questions too..Thanks again

Comment: +1 Egor - absolutely brilliant! @RaJA - if you have just the number (without any letters) you can turn it into an ordinal (1st, 203rd, 92nd, etc) like this: `number || DECODE(MOD(number, 10), 1, 'st', 2, 'nd', 3, 'rd', 'th')`, but this only works if the number is completely isolated - any non-digit values and it'll blow up. Definitely use Egor's solution for your situation.

Comment: Thanks Grace..Your solution is also a good way to make it work.Great Really appreciate your effort and time